# Choosing a javascript build tool that support ie8

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp, webpack, build-tools

It's the first time I am looking for a javascript build tool, so the very known are gulp, grunt, webpack... the main thing I need is to separate my big js file into separate files and automate the minifying process into one output file. one other thing is that I still need support for IE8 in my library but I've heard that these tool have issues with IE8 (older browsers generally), is that true ? what tool is recommended in my case ?

Comment: The only recommendation is to not support IE(8).

Comment: why do you want to split a big JS-file apart, just to concat these parts again? why not minifying the whole thing?

Comment: @Thomas it's a pain to maintain :)

Comment: then split the JS in the first place into different files, so you can handle it. it's no problem to concat them later; but it sounded like you would want the build-step to split them, just to concat them again a moment later.

Comment: @Thomas do you mean contact them manually ?

Comment: no, I mean to split them manually, into the structure you want. concatenating is easy, there are plenty of plugins for that, even most minifyer can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build system have nothing to do with browser support.

Comment: are you using es6 without problem in older browsers ?

Comment: @medBo you are mixing things up: a build-system and a JS-preprocessor ain't the same thing, although you often use build-systems to run jour code through the proprocessor

Comment: @Thomas I know the difference, I was just asking him because I was thinking about using babel and switch to es6 too

Comment: Babel is transpiling ES6 to ES5 but does not add functions like Object.assign, Array.from etc. That's why you should trigger require('babel-polyfill') on front-end.